# Why is my code not probing me to the if or elif section?

Tags: python, if-statement

The code below only skips me to the else: part...

```
print ("Welcome to my first program")
print ("Do you want to play my game ?")

x = "Start"
z = "Stop"

print("Options are: ")

print ("1",x)
print ("2",z)

Answer = input("Answer here: ")

a = Answer

if a = x :
    print (Answer,"So you want to play")

elif a = z :
     print (Answer,"So you do not want to play")

else :
     print ("Invalid entry...")
     print ("Try again next time.")

print ("Doneringo")
```

Comment: Your if statements should be `if a == x` not `if a=x`

Comment: So the user entered "2" and you compare it with "Start" and "Stop". Which of those comparisons do you think should be True?

Comment: `if a = x` is invalid python, the script cant even run like this

Comment: Your inputs will be 1 or 2 but you are checking for `Start` and `Stop`. You need to revisit how you are checking for data once you fix your if statement comparison operator

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

1. Your if statement is not correct. You have to give `==` instead of `=`
2. You are asking using to answer `1` or `2` but you are checking if the answer is `Start` or `Stop`. You need to change that.

Here's the modified code:

```
print ("Welcome to my first program")
print ("Do you want to play my game ?")

x = "Start"
z = "Stop"

print("Options are: ")

print ("1",x)
print ("2",z)

Answer = input("Answer here: ")

a = Answer

if a == '1' :  # changed to == instead of =. Also checking against 1 instead of x
    print (Answer,"So you want to play")

elif a == '2' : # changed to == instead of =. Also checking against 1 instead of z
     print (Answer,"So you do not want to play")

else :
     print ("Invalid entry...")
     print ("Try again next time.")

print ("Doneringo")
```

Results of this will be:

Run #1 with answer = 1

```
Welcome to my first program
Do you want to play my game ?
Options are: 
1 Start
2 Stop
Answer here: 1
1 So you want to play
Doneringo
```

Run #2 with answer = 2

```
Welcome to my first program
Do you want to play my game ?
Options are: 
1 Start
2 Stop
Answer here: 2
2 So you do not want to play
Doneringo
```

Run #3 with answer = Start

```
Welcome to my first program
Do you want to play my game ?
Options are: 
1 Start
2 Stop
Answer here: Start
Invalid entry...
Try again next time.
Doneringo
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has errors
Change it to this.

```
x = "Start"
z = "Stop"

print("Options are: {} or {}" .format(x,z))

Answer = input("Answer here: ")

if Answer == x :
    print (Answer,"So you want to play")

elif Answer == z :
     print (Answer,"So you do not want to play")

else :
     print ("Invalid entry...")
     print ("Try again next time.")

print ("Doneringo")
```